# Custom Account Controller Causes 404 On Address Book

Tags: magento

I've encountered a problem in our Magento installations that I've been having a really hard time tracking down. Whenever a customer goes to the "My Account" page and clicks the "Address Book" link, it sends them to the default 404 CMS page. I searched around Google and found a few similar problems, but they weren't quite the same. However, one solution that was offered was that a custom login redirect module was the cause.

So I started disabling all of our custom modules one by one to see if that would fix the problem, and it turned out that disabling our custom Account Controller fixes the problem. I tried to track this down further by using Mage::log() in the overridden methods to see if they were getting called when trying to access /customer/address/, but nothing showed up in the logs.

The only lead I have left is that it's a problem with my controller configuration. This is the config.xml I have set up:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mymodule_login>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </mymodule_login>
    </modules>
<frontend>
   <routers>
      <mymodule_login>
         <use>standard</use>
         <args>
             <module>MyModule_Login</module>
             <frontName>customer</frontName>
         </args>
      </mymodule_login>
   </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
  <rewrite>
    <mymodule_login>
      <from><![CDATA[#^/account/#]]></from>
      <to>/customer/account/</to>
    </mymodule_login>
  </rewrite>
<blocks>
<customer>
    <rewrite>
        <register-login>MyModule_Login_Block_View</register-login>
    </rewrite>
    </customer>
    <login>
        <class>RegisterLogin</class>
    </login>
  </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

I think it might be a problem with the rewrite from #^/account/# to /customer/account/, but I don't know enough about Magento rewrites to determine if that's accurate or not. The methods I have overwritten are: loginPostAction, _loginPostRedirect, and _welcomeCustomer.

Comment: I think you already answered your own question. The problem is most likely causer by your modules rewrite or/and routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dick Laurent was right - it was my configuration. All I did was add a second controller that overrode Mage_Customer_AddressController and now it works fine. The problem was that my frontend name was "customer" so it was expecting to find the corresponding controller in my custom module for when it went to the URL /customer/address/.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override Mage_Customer_AccountController, however you can't simply just override just one controller, you have to override the whole module.

So here is how you solve in this situation. You create files that reference the parent.

NOTE: Replace {Namespace} with your custom namespace.

Here is my config.xml: (inside the folder app/code/local/{Namespace}/Customer/etc)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <{Namespace}_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </{Namespace}_Customer>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module before="Mage_Customer">{Namespace}_Customer</module>
                    <frontName>customer</frontName>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now overriding Mage_Customer_AccountController: (inside the folder app/code/local/{Namespace}/Customer/controllers)

```
<?php

require_once ('Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php');

class {Namespace}_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
protected function _loginPostRedirect()
    {

        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/index')){
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
            return;
        }
        return parent::_loginPostRedirect();

    }
}
```

This redirects the customer back to their cart page after they login though checkout. We did this, because if there is an item in their cart from a previous session, Magento will combine the recent cart items with the ones from the previous session and proceed to payment without telling the customer. So to avoid customer complaints we simply redirect back to cart so the customer can see that this happens.

Now because we are overriding the entire module, we have to create the aforementioned files that reference the parent. The two other controllers under Mage_Customer are Mage_Customer_AddressController and Mage_Customer_ReviewController. Your Magento instance may vary as versions change, so make sure you check the parent folder, located at (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers), and **NEVER DIRECTLY EDIT CORE!**

Here we reference the parent for Mage_Customer_AddressController: (inside the folder app/code/local/{Namespace}/Customer/controllers)

```
<?php

require_once ('Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php');

class {Namespace}_Customer_AddressController extends Mage_Customer_AddressController
{
}
```

Likewise for Mage_Customer_ReviewController: (same file location)

```
<?php

require_once ('Mage/Customer/controllers/ReviewController.php');

class {Namespace}_Customer_ReviewController extends Mage_Customer_ReviewController
{
}
```

Without these files Magento simply can't find the controllers and throws a 404.

Lastly, create a file under app/etc/modules called {Namespace}_Customer.xml to enable your override, and address book should no longer 404.